# .htaccess RewriteRule: is this the correct way?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a project with somebody who want to move content from IP.Board to her custom forum system.
We are only 1 step away from completion, but this last step gives us a "500" server error.
Now I want to ask, is this the correct rewrite rule?

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?/file/(.*)-(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/index.php?page=file&id=$1 [R=301, L]
```

If not, how should it read like?

Comment: you rule is incorrect and it will never match as you are matching against query strings in Rule's pattern and there is an unexpected space in flags.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but how do we do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?/file/([^-]*)-([^/]*)/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/index.php?page=file&id=%1 [R=301,L]
```